# Mobx, filter and unshift an array in @computed

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mobx, computed-properties

Given an observable array holding an id-name-propertyName collection I'm trying to filter out a country array which has to be bound to a html select control in a React component. I need to present an empty default in my select html element. The filter for 'Country' works great, however when adding the .unshift(empty) portion I'm running into problems.

My observable:

```
class ReferenceStore {
  @observable referenceData=[];
```

My @computed so far:

```
  @computed get countries() {
    var empty = { id: 0, name: '' };
    var test = this.referenceData.filter(x => x.propertyName === "Country").unshift(empty);
    return test; 
  }
```

The problem is that this code results in the following error message in my component :

```
ReferenceStore__.a.countries.map is not a function
```

How should I go about this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) returns the new length of the array, and not the array itself.

You can do `unshift` first, and then return the array instead.

```js
@computed get countries() {
  var empty = { id: 0, name: '' };
  var test = this.referenceData.filter(x => x.propertyName === "Country");

  test.unshift(empty);

  return test; 
}
```

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting it. Thanks a million.